# Command not found when trying to execute *.bin file

Tags: command-line, genymotion

Downloaded genymotion and trying to access it by following [their instructions](https://www.genymotion.com/#!/developers/user-guide).  In the terminal, I've changed directory to where the file is, used `chmod +x genymotion-2.4.0_x64.bin` and `sudo ./genymotion-2.4.0_x64.bin` and it gives me `sudo: ./genymotion-2.4.0_x64.bin: command not found`.

Comment: All I can think of is, maybe you're in the wrong directory or maybe you spelled the file name wrong...

Comment: You don't need `sudo` ..run `./genymotion-2.4.0_x64.bin -d "$PWD"`

Comment: I tried originally to not use sudo, but it came back `Permission denied`  What is "$PWD"?

Comment: $PWD is the current working directory (try `echo $PWD`). If you are in the right directory, the file should appear in the output of `ls`

Comment: @Wilf that still should be substituted even without echo

Comment: @Serg - I know :), `echo $PWD` is just a demonstration of what it does

Comment: Wow, $PWD is helpful.  I was typing out a long string of folders.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Solved by OP in Question

> I was trying to execute it from the directory I had it in which was in a different partition than my home folder.  I moved it to home and right clicked and selected `Allow executing file as program` from the permissions tab of the properties, followed the previous steps adding the directory I *was* in as the install folder, and it worked.  Which only opens up new questions for me...  Why couldn't I execute the file in the target folder, why couldn't I click `Allow executing file as program` in the original directory, and why did I have to move the `.bin` file to the home folder?